# What are some good boilerplate examples of expressjs API clients on github?

Tags: reactjs, express, apiclient

Preferably with express+react on front
Express isnt serving up content because it will be fetching from a 3rd party api, so the api client wrapper can be server side

i.e. This is a good one I've used for projects before
https://github.com/esausilva/example-create-react-app-express
another one
https://github.com/recombee/node-api-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can use MERN stack, i've used it a lot in the past. You could try it. [MERN Github](https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter)

... or if you want some cool CLI setup. you can do it, like:

```
npm install -g mern-cli
mern init myApp
cd myApp
npm install
npm start
```